# "a minimal relationship in which" or "a minimal relationship to which"

Tags: prepositions

I need some help with the below sentence. Does "in which" sound right? is this grammatically correct?

> Psychological contact can be described as a minimal relationship in which there is an acknowledged connection between both parties and their experience of one another.

Should it be "a minimal relationship in which" or "a minimal relationship to which"?

Answer (score -1):

The example is fine though I suggest we change the *one another* to *each other* as there are just 2 parties.

> Psychological contact can be described as a minimal relationship in which there is an acknowledged connection between both parties and their experience of *each other*.

*in which* introduces the clause *there is an acknowledged connection between both parties and their experience of each other*, which modifies *relationship*.

**Edit**

The relative pronoun refers to *relationship*.  The sentence can be split into two:

> Psychological contact can be described as a minimal relationship.
> *In* this relationship, there is an acknowledged connection between both parties and their experience of each other.

Using *to* would not work:

> **To* this relationship, there is an acknowledged connection ...